# Optimization - open excel file from VB.NET using interop

Tags: beginner, vb.net

I have a simple app, which is something like a **launcher for my macro enabled excel workbook**. I made it for easier distribution, to be able to check if excel installed and also to make it look and behave like a standalone application.

I am **using Office Interop** which, according to MS, has many performance issues. But still, have you got any idea what I could improve to perform faster?

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module Module1
Public Sub Main()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim singleInstance As Boolean = False
    Dim mutex As New Mutex(True, My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, 
    singleInstance)
    Dim excelKey As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Excel.Application")
    Dim excelInstalled As Boolean = If(excelKey Is Nothing, False, True)
    If excelInstalled = True And singleInstance = True Then
        SplashForm.Show()
        Dim MyAppPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
        Dim ExcelFilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "Správce rozpisů 2019\" & "Rozpis1.xlsb")

        If Not IO.File.Exists(ExcelFilePath) Then
            Dim ExcelfileBackupPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\backup\" & "Rozpis1.xlsb")
            If IO.File.Exists(ExcelfileBackupPath) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(ExcelfileBackupPath, ExcelFilePath, True)
                Call Open(ExcelFilePath)
            Else
                SplashForm.Close()
                ErrorForm.ShowDialog()
                End
            End If
        Else
            Call Open(ExcelFilePath)
        End If
        SplashForm.Close()
    ElseIf excelInstalled = False Then
        SplashForm.Close()
        CompatibilityErrorForm.ShowDialog()
    ElseIf singleInstance = False Then
        MsgBox("Správce rozpisů je již spuštěn.", vbInformation, "Aplikace je již spuštěna")
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox("Při spouštění Správce rozpisů došlo k chybě.", vbCritical, "Došlo k chybě")
    Resume Next
End Sub

Sub Open(openThis As String)
    Dim xls As Application = New Application With {
        .WindowState = XlWindowState.xlMaximized
    }
    Dim workbook As Workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(openThis)
    xls.Visible = True
End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interop is surely enough for this purpose. To *manipulate* workbooks, fill in 10.000th of cells then I usually use SpreadsheetLight (http://spreadsheetlight.com/), a free, MIT licensed .NET library that works on the XML level of the Excel files and is incredibly fast compared to the Application.Excel object.

From the point of code review, I think you could dive a bit more into VB​*.NET*, your code still has the feeling of being VB6 or VBA. Why don't you switch to try/catch error handling for example? I assure you, you are going to like it. And as a rule of thumb, never compile any path/file names into your application, put them into app.config (especially if this is a standalone application) or into start parameters (especially if this application is called from within an enterprise database application).